# Simply the following fraction

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Simplify:

$$\frac {(25a^6b^2)^{1/2}}{\sqrt[3]{729(ab)^6}} = 2ab$$

Sorry my mathjax skills aren't very good.

I would assume we simplify the top first, correct?  So $12.5a^3b^1$?

I am just unsure what to do next.  Thanks

Comment: The square root of 25 isn't 12.5. Other than that, you're off to a good start.

Comment: I assume you meant to place the $(ab)^6$ under the cube root sign, along with the digits 29.  If we are simplifying the fraction, what is with the $=2ab$ at the end?

Answer (score 2):

$$\dfrac{(25a^6b^2)^{1/2}}{\sqrt[3]{729(ab^6)}}=2ab$$
First step. Remember that $\sqrt[3]{729(ab)^6}=(729(ab)^6)^{1/3}$
$$\dfrac{5a^3b}{9a^2b^2}=2ab$$
Divide top and bottom by $a^2b$:
$$\dfrac{5a}{9b}=2ab$$
Divide both sides by $a$:
$$\dfrac{5}{9b}=2b$$
Multiply both sides by $9b$:
$$5=18b^2$$
divide both sides by $18$ and extract the square root:
$$b=\sqrt{\dfrac{5}{18}}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\frac {(25a^6b^2)^{1/2}}{\sqrt[3]{729(ab)^6}} = \frac {5a^3b}{9a^2 b^2} 
= \frac {5a}{9b} = 2ab
$$

$$
b = \sqrt\frac{5}{18}
$$